# Custom Adapter in Fragment

Tags: android, android-listview, android-fragments, android-listfragment, custom-adapter

I have a listview with customAdapter.

There is `main activity` (with a list). and a `custom adapter class` (which fill each row of the list in main activity) and a setter and getter class (for setting and getting special instructions like setText, setCheched, ...).

This app works great. I want to change it like master detail/flow template (So I'm forced to use from two fragments). I want the detail fragment to be my former listview that I described above. I tried changing the activity to Fragment and adding two fragments to main layout corresponding to my "details" and "items" classes.

I tried to change my former `main activity` to `detail class` which extends `Fragment`.
But I get error that can't inflate...

What is the idea? Thanks in advance.

Comment: My crystal ball is at the shop for repairs, so maybe you want to post some code.

Comment: Sorry, I just broke your crystal ball, while servicing it, and stupidly dropping it, code will really be useful.

Comment: Post your code with error log